# Internet connectivity: ping works, telnet does not, connecting to a VPN solves all internet connectivity

Tags: vpn, internet

I am running Windows 10, ethernet to a router acting in client mode to connect to a a wifi network.

If I try to ping google.com, it resolves, and gives me fantastic ping results.
I try to telnet, it hangs on trying to connect for minutes and never actually fails.
Browsers do not work, and I've tried IE, Chrome,FF.
Oddly enough, two other things do work. The first is particularly confusing to me: other than ping, the only other thing that works, is Steam chat. No other function of steam, just logging in and chat work fine. The second thing, is that if I connect using OpenVPN to an outside server, internet works for everything, browsers, telnet, etc. The moment I disconnect from the VPN, everything drops back down to only ping and steam chat working.

I've done the usual, flushdns, winsock fix, uninstalled ethernet drivers and reinstalled, uninstalled antivirus, firewall is off. There's nothing wrong with the client or the wifi network, as a laptop plugged into the same ethernet will work fine.

*Edit: Interestingly enough, plugging the desktop directly into a router via long ethernet works perfectly fine, using the same network connections as when plugged into the client. (This is a naive question, but are there specific settings which are connection specific in this sense?)

Any suggestions or hints of what I can do? I am at my wits end trying to figure out what this combination of observations mean!

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to know how you set up your router, what model router it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Apparently, "Steam Friends" instant messaging uses UDP. Check if OpenVPN is using UDP. Ping uses ICMP. DNS uses UDP. It makes me wonder if just TCP packets aren't making it through.  It's somewhere to start.

Suggestions:

See if you can find any reason TCP cannot be transferred on your network devices such as router and client. You can test with other UDP (or other) applications to see if I'm correct.

Comment: He specifically asked for suggestions or hints. There is no way to solve this problem without further troubleshooting. I have answered the question.

Comment: I did my best at making it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bridge through a WiFi client connection. If you could, we wouldn't need WDS configured in the access point -- we could just connect as a regular client and bridge.

The problem is that the WiFi specification prohibits an access point from transmitting a packet not bound for one of its clients. If every access point broadcast every packet, wireless bandwidth would be wasted as many packets bound for wired hosts were broadcast by every single access point on the segment. That would be a disaster.

With the router in client mode, it is a single client with a single endpoint. A VPN solves the problem because then you present only a single endpoint, which will work.

Think about a packet going over the wireless link from the access point to the router. It only has a single destination hardware address. Well, whose hardware address should that be? If it's not the router, then the access point is prohibited from sending it over the wireless link since the router is its client. But if it is the router, how will it get bridged to the Windows machine?

WDS permits each packet to have more than one hardware source address and hardware destination address. So a packet sent over the wireless link can be sent to the router as the wireless destination but then marked to go to the Windows machine as the wired destination. Access points can register multiple wired hardware addresses to be associated with their wireless endpoint. This permits seamless bridging over WiFi.

You may be able to configure your router to do some version of MAC NAT that permits it to present multiple clients as a single client. This is sometimes called "repeater mode". But it's much better to use WDS, since it's intended for this exact purpose.

You could also use the router to route over the wireless link instead of bridging. This can be done with the router doing NAT or without the router doing NAT. Without NAT, changes to the configuration of the router that connects this network to the Internet will likely be needed.

Comment: The services that happen to be associated with the hardware address that happens to be the one accepted by the access point will work, others won't. The pattern of what works and what doesn't work can depend a lot on how the access point does its bridging and precisely what mode the router he's wired to is in. (Aftermarket firmware is frequently quite happy to violate the WiFi specification to make things better while manufacturers really want that compliance badge. The point is that the access point has every right not to send these packets over the wireless link -- it's not supposed to work.

Comment: I've done this before with routers and it works fine. Your answer doesn't explain why DNS, ping and steam chat work.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin I'm not sure what you mean by "this". Do you mean you bridged to a client connection without using any form of MAC NAT? If so, and it worked, then your access point violates the WiFi specification. Some do, particularly with aftermarket firmware. But many don't. (Think about it, how would it decide which packets to send over that link?) I agree that it can be difficult to explain why something that isn't guaranteed to work works. But it's much more important to understand why things that you expect to work aren't guaranteed to work.

Comment: This means I've used wireless routers in client mode, the way he is describing it. Some devices have this feature and it works great. It is not the same as a bridge. It is using wifi rather than the internet port and uses NAT to allow wired clients to access the network.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin There's no evidence the OP is using NAT and lots of evidence that he isn't -- he's having precisely the type of problems you have when you don't. And my experience has not been that it works "great". It works well if you have a single IP segment, all your traffic is IP, you don't use multicast, and WiFi devices don't roam. It works with various degrees of success in more complex setups. WDS works great.